# Change class on span tag onClick inside Button tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="wavesurfer.playPause()" type="button">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></button>
```

When I press this button I want the span class to change:

From: `class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"`

To: `class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"`

http://jsfiddle.net/fnfNm/35/ Ive looked att this example but it doesnt have a class before it changes.

Please give me jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this:

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary playPauseBtn" onclick="myFunction()" type="button">
  <span id="playPauseSpanId" class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function myFunction(){
    wavesurfer.playPause();

    if(wavesurfer.isPlaying() == true){
        document.getElementById("playPauseSpanId").className ="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"

    }else {
        document.getElementById("playPauseSpanId").className ="glyphicon glyphicon-play"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here small algorithm for change class.

```js
var playPauseBtn = document.querySelector('.playPauseBtn');

if(playPauseBtn){
  var span = document.querySelector('.playPauseBtn .glyphicon');
  playPauseBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (span) {
      if (span.classList.contains('glyphicon-play')) {
        span.classList.remove('glyphicon-play');
        span.classList.add('glyphicon-pause');
      } else {
        span.classList.remove('glyphicon-pause');
        span.classList.add('glyphicon-play');
      }
    }
  },false);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button class="btn btn-primary playPauseBtn" onclick="wavesurfer.playPause()" type="button">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Is there any other solutions because I cannot use playPause its a method for Wavesurfer.

Comment: Everything seems alright with the code but I dont get it to work o.o